# Correct quoting to pass a shell variable to perl

Tags: bash, shell, variables, quotes, double-quotes

I'm trying to spawn some dummy processes. The `/path/to` is the same for each, but I can't seem to get the `DAEMON` name to print. The result using the code below is 2 processes called `/path/to/`. How can I achieve `/path/to/test1D` and `/path/to/test2D`?

```
declare -a DAEMONS=('test1D' 'test2D')

for i in "${DAEMONS[@]}"
do
    perl -e '$0="/path/to/'$i'"; sleep infinity' &
done
```

Comment: Mind you, substituting variables into code -- as done here -- is a serious security no-no: if this were ever reused in a scenario where the variables could have user-provided values, they could escape their quoting and run arbitrary commands in the Perl interpreter. Better would be to pass your shell variables through the environment, and refer to the `ENV` hash in your perl code.

Comment: Good tip @CharlesDuffy. This is a test script that will never be executed in a production environment, so I am ignoring security hazards. Those who may use something like this in an "exposed-to-the-world" environment should heed your advice.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, all-caps names for your own shell variables are bad form: Shell variables share a namespace with environment variables, and environment variables follow the conventions given in the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (wherein all-caps names are reserved for system use -- hence PATH and other system-impacting variables being all-caps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
perl -e "\$0='/path/to/$i'; sleep infinity" &
```

By using double-quotes as surrounding quotes, you can specify the string that should be evaluated by Perl, but keep the ability to use shell variables:

Because everything starting with `$` will now be seen as a shell variable, so the shell will try to parse `$0`. But you want it to end up as `$0` in Perl, so you'll need to escape the `$` sign. That's why you see `\$0` here.

We leave `$i` intact, so the shell will substitute it with the value of `i`.

So asuming the value of `i` is `test1D`, Perl will now receive:

```
$0='/path/to/test1D'; sleep infinity
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I discovered that previous solutions I had tried worked also, but to a certain limit. I.e., `/4chr/4chr/3ch/DAEMON` creates process `/4chr/4car/3ch/`, but `/4chr/DAEMON` creates process (as it should) `/4chr/DAEMON`. You wouldn't happen to know why this character limit is there, would you?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. And I'm fairly sure I can't say without seeing the actual code that causes that problem. Sounds to me like a new question :)

Comment: The process names are truncating after a certain character limit. Probably an issue with my environment. Thanks!

Comment: @wanovak, if I had to guess, the issue with the prior attempts sounds to me less like a character limit, and more like content parsing in an unexpected way. See if that could be reproduced if you added more characters that *aren't* slashes (or whitespace, or otherwise interesting). There _are_ command-line character limits, but unless you have so much content in your environment variables to already be very close to ARG_MAX, it's exceedingly improbable that you're hitting them.

Answer (score 1):

A safer alternative is to pass data through the environment, rather than substituting into code:

```
declare -a DAEMONS=('test1D' 'test2D')

for i in "${DAEMONS[@]}"
do
    daemon="$i" perl -e '$0="/path/to/" + $ENV{daemon}; sleep infinity' &
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to let you know, you don't need arrays for something like this:

```
daemons="test1D test2D"

for deamon in $daemons
do
    perl -e '$0="/path/to/'$daemon'"; sleep infinity' &
done
```

Or, even better:

```
set test1D test2D
for daemon in $*
do
    perl -e '$0="/path/to/'$daemon'"; sleep infinity' &
done
```

Comment: No. Not better at all, *dangerous*. Look at what happens when `daemons` contains, say, `*`, or `foo[bar]` (with `nullglob` enabled or a file named `foob` existing in the current directory).

Comment: Using `$*` unquoted instead of `"$@"` is also a very bad practice -- it means you can't pass `"value with spaces"` as a member of your list. Moreover, unlike the first change you're suggesting, this has no compatibility benefit over the best-practices approach.

Comment: Moreover, the result of the quoting in `perl -e '$0="/path/to/'$daemon'"; sleep infinity' &` is that `$daemon` is expanded unquoted -- and thus subject to string-splitting and glob expansion. At *minimum*, use `perl -e '$0="/path/to/'"$daemon"'"; sleep infinity'`, thus quoting the expansion and suppressing these steps.